# How is the "glibc-common" dependency of "glibc.i686" in OracleLinux 8.6 fulfilled?

Tags: rpm, dependencies, oracle-linux

OracleLinux 8.6 contains the 32-bit package `glibc-2.28-189.1.0.1.el8.i686.rpm`. This package requires `glibc-common` in exactly that version:

```
$ rpm -qpv --requires glibc-2.28-189.1.0.1.el8.i686.rpm 
...
manual: glibc-common = 2.28-189.1.0.1.el8
...
```

However, the [repositories](https://yum.oracle.com/oracle-linux-8.html) don't contain `glibc-common-2.28-189.1.0.1.el8.i686.rpm`, only `glibc-common-2.28-189.1.0.1.el8.x86_64.rpm`.

Can the 64-Bit version of `glibc-common` fulfill the dependency requirement of the 32-Bit `glibc` package? If so, why is it not considered `noarch`, and how would the RPM dependency resolver figure out that it has to pull in the 64-Bit variant of the RPM package?

Alternatively, is there a repository in which *exactly* this release of `glibc-common.i686` is provided? I'm aware of the [Koji](https://koji.mbox.centos.org/koji/buildinfo?buildID=21056) repository, but that only provides `glibc-common-2.28-189.el8.i686.rpm`, *not* `2.28-189.1.0.1.el8`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the 64-bit version of `glibc-common` satisfies the 32-bit `glibc` dependency. It can’t however be a `noarch` package because it contains “common binaries for the GNU libc libraries, as well as national language (locale) support” — which means that its contents vary on each architecture where it *is* built.

RHEL 8 and its derivatives only support 64-bit platforms, so the only scenario in which you can install `glibc.i686` is as a 32-bit variant of `glibc.x86_64`. The resolver will consider “main architecture” packages if a same-architecture dependency isn’t available; in this specific case, the dependency will already be resolved anyway, there won’t be anything more to install.